# How to create recyclerview like facebook in android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-recyclerview

I want to create Recyclerview like Faacebook in android application (Images and data combination).

Comment: Check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/) and get idea from it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cardview with recycleview please check below link

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Answer (score -1):

For creating recyclerview like facebook you need to create raw layout for the recyclerview and the you need to inflate it in the adapter and fill the data.

Comment: This should be a comment.